# both then and catch functions are executing in firebase database React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

When I run below code both functions run and both consoled out on terminal. Can someone help me out with it? What's wrong their? I am using **firebase library** in **expo react-native**.

```
firebase.database().ref('pendingInvoices/').push(invoice).then(function(data) {
            //success callback
            console.log('Successfuly pushed')
            dispatch(updatePendingInvoices(invoice))
            Alert.alert('Successfully added to Invoices', 'Please clear your invoice first to completely register', [{ text: 'Ok' }])
        }).catch(function(error) {
            //error callback
            console.log('Something went wrong')
            Alert.alert("Can't book package.", 'Please check your internet connection!', [{ text: 'OK', style: 'destructive' }])
        })
```

Comment: It seems extremely unlikely that both the `then()` and the `catch()` block of a promise are executed. Are you sure the entire block isn't being called multiple times? Is there any way you can set up a reproduction somewhere we can see it?

Comment: It solved @FrankvanPuffelen . It was because of dispatch statement that was throwing an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens if the `then` method itself throws an exception as the small demo below illustrates

```js
new Promise(resolve => resolve())
  .then(() => {
     console.log("resolved");
     throw "oh no something went wrong"
  })
  .catch(ex => {
    console.log("in catch:", ex);
  })
```

So, looking at your code I would assume either of the following 2 lines is throwing an error

```
dispatch(updatePendingInvoices(invoice))
Alert.alert('Successfully added to Invoices', 'Please clear your invoice first to completely register', [{ text: 'Ok' }])
```

More likely the 1st line I would think!

Comment: Thank u so much brother!! because of dispatch it's throwing error but how dispatching is throwing an error??? Can you explain?

Comment: @MuhammadRafehAtique I'm sorry, I do not know what `dispatch` is.

Comment: Ok no problem bro, It's a redux in react-native app.